# S3 disable listing and get 404 instead of 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have public S3 bucket. I want to configure it in a way that directory listing is disabled. Following config:

```
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::_my_bucket_/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::_my_bucket_"
        }
    ]
}
```

behaves like that:

1. `curl -I https://_my_bucket_.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<not_existing_object>` responds 404, good
2. `curl -I https://_my_bucket_.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<existing_object>` responds 200, good
3. `curl -I https://_my_bucket_.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/` responds 200 and prints every object in my bucket, **bad**

If I remove `s3:ListBucket` I effectively disable "directory-listing" but I break 404s (as described in [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-rest-api-cloudfront-error-403/)).

```
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::_my_bucket_/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

It behaves like that:

1. `curl -I https://_my_bucket_.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<not_existing_object>` responds 403, **bad**
2. `curl -I https://_my_bucket_.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<existing_object>` responds 200, good
3. `curl -I https://_my_bucket_.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/` responds 200 and prints every object in my bucket, good

Is it possible to configure s3 (without using CloudFront (I am not sure it is possible with CF either)) so it behaves like that:

1. `curl -I https://_my_bucket_.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<not_existing_object>` responds 404
2. `curl -I https://_my_bucket_.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<existing_object>` responds 200
3. `curl -I https://_my_bucket_.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/` responds 200 and prints every object in my bucket

Answer (score 1):

S3 gives 404 only if Listbucket permissions is present. I have one solution in mind using CloudFront.

1. Restrict access to S3 form CloudFront using OAI.
2. Configure Default root object as e.g: index.html.
3. Give CloudFront OAI both GETObject and Listbucket permissions.

curl -I https://d123xxxxx.cloudfront.net/ --> fetches default root document instead of listing all the objects of S3.

curl -I https://https://d123xxxxx.cloudfront.net/not_existing_object --> you'll still get 404.